# unable to setup keycloak docker container with SSL

Tags: ssl, keycloak

I am trying to setup keycloak docker container with SSL but it is not working.

Here is the docker run command i used:

```
docker run -p 7443:8443 -p 7080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password -v ~/keycloak-config/standalone.xml:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml -v ~/keycloak-config/ct.jks:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/ct.jks  -d jboss/keycloak
```

Here is how standalone.xml file looks like:

```
 <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="ct.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="123456" />
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
        </security-realm>


<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm"/>


 <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public"
                     port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management"
                  port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management"
                  port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

I am trying to access keycloak using IP address of machine.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: It's not working => can you tell a bit more ?

Comment: Hi Mat, I am assuming you are also facing the same issue. I ended up configuring keycloak behind nginx. So nginx on https and keycloak on http.... or you want more information from my side to help me resolve the original issue - setting up keycloak on https without nginx

Comment: Was just willing to help you as I struggled with keycloak+SSL for a while. Ended up configuring it behind Nginx too though :-) I used a recent keycloak docker image, allowing me to use PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true env parameter. Easy.

Comment: @Mat With this comment I want to thank you so, so much. This worked for me in an other case.

Comment: @alexander You're welcome - I'm usually borrowing help from others, so glad I can help this time.